# Get the current file directory from file dialog directory Adobe Extendscript

Tags: adobe, extendscript

I have a script that will automatically point a user to a folder on a UNC path/shared folder on a server to allow them to load files InDesign library files from.

The purpose of the script is to eliminate that need for the user to change directory to this folder from their local PC.

After running the script, it will immediately put them into the folder they need. However, they can also navigate up the file server tree and into other subdirectories to get at other files.

If the user decides to change the file directory to a different folder in the tree, when they run the script again it will 'remember' the last folder they were in.

User does not want this to happen. They would like the script to put them into the SAME originating folder every time it is ran regardless of if they have changed the directory.

Is it possible to call and use some kind of GetCurrentDirectory method or folder with Adobe Extendscript? It would need to get the current folder from the active 'open file dialog' window and change it.

I have looked at Adobe forums and other resources online but can't seem to easily find any sort of function or method that can achieve this.

If anyone can shed some light, that would be useful.

```
function loadLibs()
{
    var serverPath = "\\" + "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    var folderDlg = Folder(serverPath);
    if (folderDlg.exists)
    {
        var libraryItem = folderDlg.openDlg("Choose the library file(s) you want to open","*.indl",true);
        if (libraryItem == null)
        {           
            return;
        }

        else
        {
            app.open(libraryItem);
        }
        
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Cannot find InDesign libraries folder.");
        return;
    }       
}

loadLibs();
```

Comment: Do you mean a current folder of active document? `var folder = Folder(app.activeDocument.filePath);`

Comment: Hi Yuri, in this sense there is no 'active document' in play. Just the last used or last remembered file path that the user navigated to. I will give your suggestion a try. Many thanks

Comment: I just reread your question. So you have already some jsx script, do you? Do you want to change the script? It wouldn't hurt if you show the script or its part. If it has some path at some moment it can be saved in the temp folder as a txt file and read back any time. I'm doing something like this pretty often. Let me know if you want to see how it can be done in a general way. But the final implementation probably heavily depends on the script you have.

Comment: Hi Yuri, script has been added. The var serverPath has been omitted as it is a company UNC path and I cannot expose that online. However, the format is a standard UNC path: \\servername\folder1name\folder2name

Comment: As far as I can see from the code the script provides user the same folder every time you run the script. It doesn't change the variable `serverPath`. So what do you want? *They would like the script to put them into the SAME originating folder every time it is ran* It does exactly this. Or do you mean by the 'same folder' not the same, but the current (last opened) one?

Comment: Hi Yuri, sorry for late reply. Bizarrely, when running the script a second time (after running once then changing to a different folder) it DOES NOT return to the original path in the serverPath variable. The only reason I can think of that might be causing this is the fact that InDesign is running within a Citrix machine that is clean VM session every day when switched on

Comment: Yep. Citrix can causes problems. It's an important addition. I'm afraid I have no solution.

Comment: I am going to test this on a local install of InDesign that is outside of the Citrix environment to see if I get a different result.

Comment: Tired it outside of Citrix, I get the same issue. What I dont seem to understand is that the  file dialog path only changes once a file is clicked on and the Open button is clicked. Do I need to check the value of the 'serverPath' variable after loading an .INDL file to see if it has changed and then set it back?

Comment: I would glad to help, but I can't reproduce the problem. Your code shows me the same folder every time I run it, no matter how many times it happens. And it's a standard behaviour, actually. Usually it is the opposite, you have a hard time to make InDesign to remember something, you have to fiddle with the saving/loading some info on the disk (like in my ansnwer), etc.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if understand the problem correctly. It looks like the code does exactly the thing you ask -- it uses the same start folder every time you run it.

But if you want to make the script to remember the last used folder and provides it in the dialog as a start folder here is how it can be done:

```
function loadLibs() {
    // the standard folder
    var serverPath = "###";

    // try to get the last used folder
    try {
        var f = File(Folder.temp + '/temp_path.txt');
        f.open('r');
        f.encoding = 'utf8';
        serverPath = f.read();
        f.close();
    } catch(e) {}

    // dialog
    var folderDlg = Folder(serverPath);
    if (!folderDlg.exists) { alert("Cannot find InDesign libraries folder."); return; }
    var libraryItem = folderDlg.openDlg("Choose the library file(s) you want to open","*.indl",true);
    if (libraryItem == null) return;
    app.open(libraryItem);

    // try to save the current folder as the last used one
    try {
        var f = File(Folder.temp + '/temp_path.txt');
        f.open('w');
        f.encoding = 'utf8';
        f.write(libraryItem[0].parent.fsName);
        f.close();
    } catch(e) {}
}

loadLibs();
```

Note: the `libraryItem` here is an Array of Files to open.

`libraryItem[0]` is the first file.

`libraryItem[0].parent` is the current folder of the file.

Comment: Hi Yuri, thanks for providing a solution. Please could you read my comment on the original post? Many thanks